# Use Firebase Cloud Messaging in library

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-library, android-module

I have multiple feature modules and want to move fcm from my app module to a library module.

So I created a new module ("fcm") and tried to add the dependencies for firebase:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ["*.jar"], dir: "libs")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_core_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_messaging_version"
}
```

Now when I sync gradle I get: "Failed to notify project evaluation listener."

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':fcm'.
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:261)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.computeResourceSetList0(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:136)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:95)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:18)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$4.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:196)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$4.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:73)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$sam$org_gradle_api_Action$0.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:26)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.applyExperimental(AndroidSubplugin.kt:194)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:99)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:73)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.SubpluginEnvironment.addSubpluginOptions(KotlinPlugin.kt:708)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:574)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.access$processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:478)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:534)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:478)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$sam$org_gradle_api_Action$0.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:26)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:533)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:478)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
... 92 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:340)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:327)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.afterResolve(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:502)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:485)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:470)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:927)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.access$2700(DefaultConfiguration.java:861)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1279)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1257)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.computeResourceSetList(MergeResources.java:723)
... 122 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$1$_afterResolve_closure1.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:316)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.eachElement(DefaultResolutionResult.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.eachElement(DefaultResolutionResult.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.eachElement(DefaultResolutionResult.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.eachElement(DefaultResolutionResult.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.allComponents(DefaultResolutionResult.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.allComponents(DefaultResolutionResult.java:90)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolutionResult.allComponents(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:227)
at org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolutionResult$allComponents.call(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$1.afterResolve(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:308)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:370)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
... 144 more
```

Im not using the google service plugin in my library and only in my app module.
When I remove everything google service related from my app module and project I dont get the error.

Comment: *Im not using the google service plugin in my library* -- well, you need it

Comment: I read that I should only use the plugin in my app module. Using it in a library too would mean that I have to create another app in the firebase console right?

Answer (score -1):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:your system version'
```

disabling the Instant Run

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and
>   uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Hope it works.

Comment: Im not using Instant Run.